# I want kafka connect to airflow?

Tags: apache-kafka, airflow, apache-kafka-connect

I need to connect kafka with airflow send data from kafka to airflow and save it to a local file, tell me how best to do it. I thinks airflow-provider-kafka is this the correct approach, is there anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install kafka sdk and connect it via PythonOperator but it seems that "airflow-provider-kafka" wrap it and do it , so seems like its good to use it and extend it if needed.

The only reason not to use "airflow-provider-kafka" its because it developed and maintained outside of airflow repo , so in the future you can have compatibility issues and breaking changes that would prevent you to upgrade your airflow version

Answer (score 0):

> The only reason not to use "airflow-provider-kafka" its because it developed and maintained outside of airflow repo , so in the future you can have compatibility issues and breaking changes that would prevent you to upgrade your airflow version

Use the provider.

The Kafka provider in Airflow will not be breaking when you upgrade your airflow version - this is guaranteed by the Airflow project using and adhering to SemVer. Furthermore, the provider is maintained at Astronomer who has a vested commercial interest in these providers.

(Unless/Until Airflow 3 comes out, at which time it will probably be upgraded)